# StringBuffer Replace on JSON

Tags: java, json, string, stringbuffer

I have a StringBuffer object which returns a json response sent from an API Request.
I want to know what the best way would be to get only the link from this detail

```
{"thumbnailURL":"http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/d21\/unsecured\/media\/28238874477001\/201406\/1522\/283882744477001_364103224001_10bd97ac41f94f9a89a26882960ad1bb-788602308-thumbnail.jpg?pubId=2838874477001"}
```

This is stored as StringBuffer resp; 
in my code.
I want to be able to get only the link from this.
Please advise.

Thanks,

Comment: Use a JSON parser to extract the appropriate entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What library are you using for working with json? Perhaps this one:

http://www.json.org/

If so you can do it like this:

```
JSONObject myobj = JSONObject(your_buffer);
myobj.getString("thumbnailURL");
```

That is one way. Other method would be simply to use standard string functions. E.g. indexOf("http:") and then copy to the last occcurence of ".

Hope this helps